# Java Recursive about reversing a single list

Tags: java, list, recursion

Here is the code

```
public static ListCell reverse(ListCell f) {
    if (f==null)
        return null;
    else if (f.getNext()==null)
        return f;
    else {
        ListCell head = reverse(f.getNext());
        f.getNext().setNext(f);
        f.setNext(null);
        return head;
    }
}
```

I am confused about the `f.setNext(null)`. Consider the second recursive call, `reverse(f.getNext())`. But `f.getNext().next` should be `f`, not `null`. This sentence will set every `node.next` to be `null`. So I am little confused

Comment: Is this your code or something you've found?

Comment: It is the correct code that I am working on.

Comment: Are you getting the correct expected output?

Comment: It's set to `null` at its current level of recursion, but as soon as you return and go up a level, the previous call will set it to the appropriate value, unless it's the original first element, in which case it (correctly) stays `null`.

Answer (score 0):

When entering the reverse function the function recursively calls itself until the parameter f is the last element of the list (indicated by `f.getNext () == null`)

Example a List like `a -> b -> c`

The first time `f.getNext().setNext(f)` will be evaluated `f` is the second last element of the list and head is the last element.
`head = reverse(f.getNext())` head will be `c`
When `f.getNext().setNext(f)` is called f points to ListCell `b` in the example given.
So its like this call `b.getNext().setNext(b)`
The List looks like this `a-> b <- c` after `b.setNext(null)`. After that the functions returns `c` because `head` points to `c`.

After climbing up the stack `head` still points to `c` because its returned by the recursive call but f is `a`.

So `a.getNext().setNext(a)` will set the next value of `b` to a because `a.getNext()` still points to `b`.
After `a.setNext(null)` the list looks like `c->b->a`

Comment: When the first time enter the else case, I think f should be the first element, am I right?

Comment: Yes but it will call the reverse function recursively until the condition f.getNext() == null is evaluated to true. I will update the answer...